# Taking IFFT of Arbitrary Frequency Domain Signal

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I am used to moving from the time-domain, to the frequency-domain, and then back to the time-domain by:

1. taking fft of real valued time-domain signal (i.e., signal without imaginary components)
2. take ifft of frequency domain signal from step 1
3. ignore imaginary components of ifft from step 2.

However I would like to skip step 1 and, instead, define an arbitrary complex (i.e., both real and imaginary component) signal in the frequency-domain and then use an ifft to get the time-domain equivalent.

To ignore the imaginary components (as in step 3 above), several Stack posts suggest the signal needs to be conjugate symmetric (e.g., https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37272/how-to-get-a-real-signal-from-complex-ifft-values, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74163/what-is-imaginary-part-after-ifft-and-how-to-use-it).  Following the definition of a conjugate symmetric signal here:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9144/how-to-make-a-signal-conjugate-symmetric

I tried to force my arbitrary frequency-domain signal to be conjugate symmetric.  However, when I transform the conjugate symmetric frequency-domain signal to the time-domain via an ifft, I find there are still non-zero values in the imaginary components, which makes me believe I can't simply ignore them.  Interestingly, I found that the frequency domain transform of a real valued time-domain signal is not conjugate symmetric but, when transformed back to the time-domain via ifft, has insignificant (close to zero) imaginary components nonetheless.

**Am I missing the definition of a conjugate symmetric signal or is there another condition required before I can ignore the imaginary components of an ifft?  The code below illustrates my issues.**

Finally, I decided to post in StackOverflow instead of SignalProcessing given my goal is to write a python code to define my frequency domain function and transform it to the time-domain.

```
import numpy as np                                                       
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft                                          
                                                                         
# helper function to check if complex conjugate                          
def check_cc(complex_sig):                                               
                                                                         
    sig1 = complex_sig[::-1]                                             
    sig2 = np.conj(complex_sig)                                          
    sig_check = all(sig1 == sig2)                                        
    print(f"Signal Conjugate Symmetric: {sig_check}")                    
    return                                                               
                                                                         
                                                                         
""" CASE 1: Damped Sine Wave in Time Domain """                          
                                                                         
# make a damped sine wave                                                
dt = 0.01                                                                
tax = np.arange(1000) * dt + dt                                          
f = 3                                                                    
wig1 = np.exp(-1 * tax) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * tax)                    
                                                                         
# the frequency domain                                                   
WIG1 = fft(wig1)                                                          
                                                                         
# check if signal is complex conjugate symmetric                         
check_cc(WIG1)                                                           
                                                                         
# back to the time domain                                                
wig_complex = ifft(WIG1)                                                 
wig1_imag = np.imag(wig_complex)                                         
                                                                         
# print the max value of the imaginary time-domain complex signal        
print(f"Max Value of wig1 imaginary component: {np.max(wig1_imag)}")     
                                                                         
                                                                         
""" Case 2: Arbitraty Complex Signal in the Frequency Domain """         
                                                                         
WIG2_real1 = np.arange(len(tax) // 2) * 0                                
WIG2_real1[1] = 100                                                      
WIG2_real2 = WIG2_real1[::-1]                                            
WIG2_real = np.array([*WIG2_real1, *WIG2_real2])                         
                                                                         
WIG2_imag1 = np.arange(len(tax) // 2) * 0                                
WIG2_imag1[15] = 100                                                     
WIG2_imag2 = -1 * WIG2_imag1[::-1]                                       
WIG2_imag = np.array([*WIG2_imag1, *WIG2_imag2])                         
                                                                         
WIG2 = np.array([complex(r, i) for r, i in zip(WIG2_real, WIG2_imag)])   
# check if singal is complex conjugate                                  
check_cc(WIG2)                                                          
                                                                        
# to the time-domain                                                    
wig2_complex = ifft(WIG2)                                               
wig2_real = np.real(wig2_complex)                                       
wig2_imag = np.imag(wig2_complex)                                       
                                                                        
# print the max value of the imaginary time-domain complex signal       
print(f"Max Value of wig2 imaginary component: {np.max(wig2_imag)}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to establish the axis over which there is symmetry.

In the continuous-domain Fourier transform, where the frequency domain *F*(*ω*) has an infinite extent, the symmetry is over the origin. That is, *F*(*ω*) = *F*<sup>*</sup>(-*ω*). On the discrete Fourier transform (which is what the FFT computes), the frequency domain *F*[*k*] is defined over the integers *k* = 0 to *N*-1, for *N* samples. There is no *F*[-*k*]. So how do we make this signal (conjugate) symmetric?

We can take *F*[*k*] to be periodic, with *F*[*k*] = *F*[*k*+*mN*], for any integer *m*. So we can imagine a *F*[-*k*], which would be equal to *F*[*N*-*k*]. So, it follows that the symmetry is defined by *F*[*k*] = *F*<sup>*</sup>[*N*-*k*].

For this equation to hold at *k* = 0, we must make *F*[0] real-valued. Likewise, if *N* is even, *F*[*N*-*N*/2] = *F*[*N*/2], so the element at *k* = *N*/2 must also be real-valued (in the odd *N* case there is no such element).

In Python we can write:

```py
N = 1000  # length of desired signal (even!)
# Create half a 
F = np.random.rand(N//2 + 1) + 1j * np.random.rand(N//2 + 1)
F[0] = F[0].real
F[-1] = F[-1].real
F = np.concatenate((F, np.flip(np.conj(F[1:-1]))))

f = np.fft.ifft(F)
assert np.real_if_close(f).dtype == np.float64
```

To test for conjugate symmetry, we'd have to build the reverse array this way:

```py
F_flipped = np.concatenate((F[:1], np.flip(F[1:])))

np.all(np.isclose(F, np.conj(F_flipped)))
```

(Note that your check `all(sig1 == sig2)` will fail in general, you cannot compare floating-point numbers for equality, you need to include a tolerance, which is what `np.isclose()` does.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my response to those who are interested in such a question is delayed almost a year long. I have attached a Python3 code snippet as a demo answer, which I hope will be helpful.

To generate a complex 1D array in fft spectra space that represents a real-valued array in time domain, the array must be Hermitian. It means that the time-array's fft is symmetric for real parts and antisymmetric for imaginary parts. The first component of the fft array is always real. The following example generates such an array in spectra domain and an ifft retrieves the real-valued array in time domain.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a conjugate symmetric array
N = 8  # Number of elements
half_N = N // 2

# Create the first half of the array with random complex numbers
first_half = np.random.rand(half_N) + 1j * np.random.rand(half_N)

# Create a conjugate symmetric second half
second_half = np.conj(first_half[::-1])

# Construct the full conjugate symmetric array
# Note: We take care to make sure the first element is real
symmetric_fft = np.concatenate(([np.real(first_half[0])], first_half[1:], second_half))

# Perform IFFT
t_domain = np.fft.ifft(symmetric_fft)

# Plot real and imaginary parts of FFT
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)

# Input.real
ax[0].plot(symmetric_fft.real)
ax[0].set_title('Input.real)')

# Input.imag
ax[1].plot(symmetric_fft.imag)
ax[1].set_title('Input.imag')

# real.iFFT
ax[2].plot(t_domain.real)
ax[2].set_title('iFFT.real')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

print("Original symmetric array in freq domain:")
print(symmetric_fft)
print("\nReal-valued array in time domain:")
print(t_domain.real)
```

The demo code generate the first half of our spectra domain array with random complex numbers, then it creates the second half as the complex conjugate of the first half in reverse order to be matching with ifft as required.

By doing this, it may ensure that the spectra domain array is conjugate symmetric, which means that its inverse Fourier transform will be a real-valued time domain array.

In the end, the code only print the real part of the real-part of time domain array, as the imaginary part is very close to zero (due to native numerical and other error sources, it is not to be exactly zero).